# Adding a vertex with control-LMB does not work on OSX - how can I fix that or work around?

Tags: modeling, interface

A technique used in a number of tutorials is start with a mesh, delete all the vertices and then start adding new vertices with control left mouse click.

It seems this never works on a mac.  At least there are a lot of forum posts out there saying it doesn't work and asking for help.  I haven't yet found one that results in useful answer.

The user preferences, 'input' tab, shows very clearly what keys are bound to actions and allows you to reassign them but mouse gestures don't seem to be exposed to configuration with the same clarity.

I'm working on a macbook air with a three-button wheel mouse plugged in.  I've tried turning 'emulate three button mouse' on and off, I've tried working with the inbuilt trackpad instead, I've tried all the combinations of modifier keys and mouse gestures I can think of.

I have come close to using harsh language.

Does anyone know how to add a vertex to a mesh on osx?

Comment: Ctrl + LMB works for me (iMac)

Answer (score 1):

I too had the same problem. I noticed that I had was using face select instead of vertex select. Changing that might help you. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I know that this thread is a few years old, but this issue still persists, I have yet to see an answer for this issue, so I took it upon myself to do some poking around and I have found the solution. I entered user preferences, and found the shortcut for "Duplicate or Extrude to Cursor". The hot hey for this was set to Ctrl+MiddleMouse Button - even though every forum says to perform this function you must press Ctrl+LMB. I set my own hotkey sequence to Ctrl+LMB and it now works flawlessly.

Duplicate or Extrude to cursor is the equivalent of the Create Polygon tool in Maya.

Answer (score 0):

In Blender 2.8 it is CTRL + Right Mouse Button for drawing edges in Edit Mode.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the comment parameciostudio. I tried doing the simplest possible thing - ie start with a new file, delete the vertices from the default cube and start adding vertices with control LMB.  And, in fact, it does work.

As far as I can tell the mistake I made with my original project was this - I inadvertently selected an object behind the one I was trying to create.  I carried on adding junk geometry to this without getting any feedback from Blender.

It sometimes feels as if the Blender interface is cryptic to the point of actual malice!

What would be really helpful, is a feature I think is in C4D but not in Blender, where you can view and edit the geometry of an object in a numeric table.

Comment: "without getting any feedback from Blender" well, selected objects and the active object are indicated by bright orange outlines, so there's that feedback. "cryptic to the point of actual malice" okay, and how long have you been using Blender vs C4D? Biased in favor of what you already know, perhaps? "where you can view and edit the geometry of an object in a numeric table" There's the Outliner, which lets you select from a hierarchical table. Also the name of your active object is always shown in the 3D viewport, bottom left. Anyway, glad you figured it out. Blender gets easier with time ;-)